# Using JSOUP to remove duplicate elementText value

Tags: java, jsoup

I am scrapping Walmart page at URL http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?tab_value=all&search_query=camera&search_constraint=0&Find=Find&ss=false&ic=16_32 using JSOUP DOM parser in JAVA.

I am building URL based on user parameters and building a DOM object using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(contentVar);
```

For the next step i want to print all the products/price. I used the following code:

```
String price = doc.getElementsByClass("camelPrice").text();
String title = doc.getElementsByClass("ListItemLink").text();       
System.out.println("Product: " + title);
System.out.println("Price: "+ price);
```

Here i am using the tags for the price and product description. However my results are :

```
Title/Product Name: C1, C2, ... C16 (c is camera title)
Price: $279.95 $279.95 $479.00 $479.00 $60.00 $60.00 $99.00 $99.00 $429.00 $429.00 $129.00 $129.00 $109.00 $109.00 $89.00 $89.00 $384.00 $384.00 $69.00 $69.00 $279.00 $279.00 $129.00 $129.00 $55.20 - $69.00 $55.20 - $69.00 $74.00 $74.00 $119.00 $119.00
```

here the prices are duplicated because of a possible quickview tag. Is there any way to remove the duplicacy in prices using any JSOUP method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seeing the html dom I noticed that there are duplicates in the sense that there is a price

```
<div class="ItemShelfAvail">     <----------- SEE HERE
<div class="OnlinePriceAvail">
<div class="PriceHeader OnlineHead">Online</div>
<div class="PriceContent">
<div class="PriceDisplay" id="price_display_23204350_2">
<div class="PriceCompare">
<div class="camelPrice"><span class="prefixPriceText2"></span><span class="bigPriceText2">$279.</span><span class="smallPriceText2">00</span><span></span></div>
```

and a price

```
<div class="OnlinePriceAvail">
<div class="PriceHeader OnlineHead">Online</div>
<div class="PriceContent">
<div class="PriceDisplay" id="price_display_23204350_2">
<div class="PriceCompare">
<div class="camelPrice"><span class="prefixPriceText2"></span><span class="bigPriceText2">$279.</span><span class="smallPriceText2">00</span><span></span></div>
```

You must see what list you want from the two and then put a proper selector. If you want both of them just take the Elements list returned by the getElementsByClass and manipulate each price.

getElementsByClass returns Elements which is a list where every node is of type Element. You can do

```
Elements elPrice = doc.getElementsByClass("camelPrice");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this may now be useless to the creator of the thread but I found this when looking on how to find the price of a product on amazon uk.

```
String pricing = doc.getElementsByClass("priceLarge").text();
System.out.println("price : " + pricing);
```

Here is the code to do it :)

Comment: Yes it is not very useful now. Appreciate your response :)